# circular numpy array indices

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a 1-D numpy array `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` and a function that gets two inputs, `starting_index` and `ending_index`, and returns `a[staring_index:ending_index]`.

Clearly I run into trouble when `ending_index` is smaller than `starting_index`. In this case, the function should start from the starting_index and traverse the vector `a` in a circular way, i.e., return all the elements coming after `starting_index` plus all the elements from index zero to `ending_index`.

For instance, if `starting_index=4` and `ending_index=1` then the output should be `output = [5,6,1]`. I can implement it with an `if` condition but I was wondering if there is any Pythonic and concise way to do it?

Comment: this seems related: https://scimusing.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/ring-buffers-in-pythonnumpy/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`np.take` has a `wrap` mode:

```
In [171]: np.take(np.arange(1,7),range(4,7),mode='wrap')
Out[171]: array([5, 6, 1])
```

That's not quite what you want.

Actually, modulus does the same thing

```
In [177]: a[np.array([4,5,6])%6]
Out[177]: array([5, 6, 1])
```

But how about a small function that turns `(4,1)` into `[4, 5, 6]`, or if you prefer `[4, 5, 0]`?

```
def foo(a, start, stop): 
    # fn to convert your start stop to a wrapped range
    if stop<=start:
        stop += len(a)
    return np.arange(start, stop)%len(a)

a[foo(a,4,1)]  # or
np.take(a,foo(a,4,1))
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be modulo in the return statement of method foo for this to work?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunatly you cannot do this with slicing, you'll need to concatonate to two segments:

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
if starting_index > ending_index:
    part1 = a[start_index:]
    part2 = a[:end_index]
    result = np.concatenate([part1, part2])
else:
    result = a[start_index:end_index]
```

Comment: currently i'm doing something like this. Thanks. though, can't be used with numpy, would you explain more about slicing? I assume it can be used with lists?

Comment: Numpy indexing and slicing is described [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) there is also a more general discussion of slicing [here](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html).

Comment: I can confirm that this is faster than using np.roll, especially for smaller (<1e6) size arrays. E.g. for a 100 item array: np.roll: 23.4 µs ± 968 ns per loop; np.concatenate: 3.22 µs ± 61 ns  per loop. For an 1e6 item array concatenate is still marginally faster: 2.19 ms ± 82 µs vs 2.29 ms ± 92.9 µs per loop. Using scalar as in this example is also faster than using range or an index array for larger arrays

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that you can use is the numpy `roll` function combined with indexing:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np

def circular_array(starting_index, ending_index):

    idx = np.arange(1,7)
    idx = np.roll(idx, -starting_index)[:(len(idx)-starting_index+ending_index)%len(idx)]

    return idx


a = circular_array(4, 1)
print a
```

Answer (score 0):

This circles forever.

```
def circular_indices(lb, ub, thresh):
    indices = []
    while True:
        stop = min(ub, thresh)
        ix = np.arange(lb, stop)
        indices.append(ix)
        if stop != ub:
            diff = ub - stop
            lb = 0
            ub = diff
        else:
            break

    return np.concatenate(indices)
```