# NetCDF: How to extract data which crosses a boundary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, netcdf, netcdf4, cdo-climate

I have a NetCDF file with 4 dimensions: time, level, latitude and longitude.
The shape of the data is: `1, 60, 1440, 2880`

This means that there is 1 timepoint, 60 levels, 1440 latitudes and 2880 longitudes.

Latitudes range from -90 to 90 and increment by 0.125. For example:

```
lats = np.arange(-90,90.125, 0.125)
```

Longitudes range from 0 to 360 and increment by 0.125. For example:

```
lons = np.arange(0,360, 0.125)
```

I have a "Station" with a GPS location: `station.lat, station.lon = 22.125, 275.250`.
Convert the longitude to a 360 degree gridspace: `station.lon = station.lon%360.0`

I want to extract a cube about my station. For example, 5 cells left, 5 right and all levels. (including the cell in which the station resides)

To do this, I get the index of `lat` within `lats` and I get the index of `lon` within `lons`.

I then create a range of indices that I use to extract the data from the netCDF file:

```
    lat_index_range = np.arange(nearest_latitude_index-5, nearest_latitude_index+5, 1)%1441
    lon_index_range = np.arange(nearest_longitude_index-5, nearest_longitude_index+5, 1)%2881
```

Let's imagine

```
lat_index_range = [1220,1221,1223,1224,1225,1226,1227,1228,1229,1230,1231]
lon_index_range = [2250,2251,2252,2253,2254,2255,2256,2257,2258,2259,2260,2261]
```

I then extract the data:

```
factor = dataset[parameter][0]
factor[:,min(lat_index_range):max(lat_index_range),min(lon_index_range):max(lon_index_range)
```

This works fine, however, index 2880 would represent 360 degrees, so if my point was located near the boundary (i.e it had a longitude who's index was mapped to 2879), I need to spill over back to the start. My `lon_index_range` would then look something like this:

```
lon_index_range = [2879,2880,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Extracting my data now would not work...

```
factor = dataset[parameter][0]
factor[:,1220:1231,0:2879) # this would take ALL the longitude data from 0 to 2879!!
```

Likewise, I cannot have something like this: `factor[:,1220:1231,2879:8)`

The same issue exists for latitudes... as my point may be near the latitude boundary.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: I think that Numpy's `roll()` will be helpful here (and now that you have Numpy imported, you can also get rid of those ugly list comprehensions with e.g. `lons = np.arange(...)` or `np.linspace(...)`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [circular numpy array indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398220/circular-numpy-array-indices)

Comment: Thank you, but I am not asking how to create a circular array. My question is about extracting the data from the NetCDF file. Ps Thanks for the `np.arange` tip - that makes things much prettier.

Answer (score 0):

I still think that the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398220/circular-numpy-array-indices) can help. As a very minimal example;

```
import numpy as np

def cslice(a, start, stop): 
    if start > stop:
        part1  = a[start:]
        part2  = a[:stop ]
        return np.concatenate([part1, part2])
    else:
        return a[start:stop]

lons = np.arange(0,360,60)

print(lons)
print(cslice(lons, 0, 4))
print(cslice(lons, 4, 2))
```

Which results in:

```
[  0  60 120 180 240 300]
[  0  60 120 180]
[240 300   0  60]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing this from the command line it is one line in CDO:

```
cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 in.nc out.nc
```

you can specify the lon in the range -180,180 as well as 0 360 and it handles it for you.

Comment: Would it handle from 257 to 8?