# How to combine the 3 arrays I have defined below?

Tags: python, numpy, geospatial

I have a large data file of soil moisture levels (mrso) over the whole world. I want to restrict that data so that it only covers Europe.

The mrso data has dimension (time, latitude, longitude). So to restrict it to Europe, I want to restrict the latitude and longitude dimensions to Europe's dimensions. The problem is that the 0 longitude line lies on Europe. Since the longitude dimension goes from 0 to 360, I need to limit the mrso longitude from 330 to 360 and then from 0 to 45, before somehow combining them to give me the mrso for the whole of Europe.

Here is some proxy data to attempt to clarify the problem:

```
# Proxy data for latitude, longitude, time and soil moisture (mrso)
lat = np.linspace(-90, 90, 181)
lon = np.linspace(0, 360, 181)
time = np.linspace(0, 70, 71)
mrso = np.random.rand(len(time), len(lat), len(lon))
```

I have tried the following code to attempt to restrict the mrso data to europe:

```
def findNearestIndex(vals, target):
    # Finds the value within an array that is closest to the target value
    minIndex = -1
    minDiff = None
    # Loop over all the values in the given list
    for i in range(len(vals)):
        # Find the absolute difference between this value and the target
        diff = abs(vals[i] - target)
        # If this is the first time, or if the difference is smaller than
        # the smallest difference found so far, remember the difference and
        # the index
        if minDiff is None or diff < minDiff:
            minDiff = diff
            minIndex = i
    return minIndex

def EU_Restrict(lat, lon, mrso):    
    # Find min and max lat and lon of Europe
    max_lat = findNearestIndex(lat, 75)
    min_lat = findNearestIndex(lat, 35)
    max_lon = findNearestIndex(lon, 45)
    min_lon = findNearestIndex(lon, 330)
    end_lon = findNearestIndex(lon, 360) #closest point corresponding to 360/0 lon

    # Restrict mrso data to Europe
    EU_mrso = np.concatenate((mrso[:, min_lat:max_lat, min_lon:end_lon], mrso[:, min_lat:max_lat, 0:max_lon]))
    return EU_mrso
```

However, it returns the following error message:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
49     plt.show()
50
---> 51 map_EU_Restrict(5, r1i1p1f1_hist_path2000)

1 frames
 in EU_Restrict(model)
30
31     # Restrict mrso data to Europe
---> 32     EU_mrso = np.concatenate((mrso[:, min_lat:max_lat, min_lon:end_lon], mrso[:, min_lat:max_lat, 0:max_lon]))
33     return EU_mrso
34

<**array_function** internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 2, the array at index 0 has size 12 and the array at index 1 has size 17

It is the concatenate function that isn't working, but I don't know another way to achieve what I want to. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You can also use the [`roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html#numpy-roll) function from Numpy to shift your longitudes coordinates and avoid this problem altogether

Comment: Okay, thanks! for this case, would I implement np.roll onto lon? Is there a way to use roll such that a certain array entry is set to the zero position in the array? e.g. in this case so that 330 is set to be the first positions of the array. I only ask because I'm hoping to apply this to different datasets and don'r necessarily know the positions of 33o degrees in each

Comment: Imo, you would have to use it both on `lon` and in `mrso` (to the last dimension - the one corresponding to lon) so there is a good correspondence between coordinates and values. Anyways, take a look at this old question, which basically describes your exact problem: [circular numpy array indices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28398220/8345628)

Comment: Thanks again. How would you apply roll onto just the last dimension of mrso? from [roll](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) it appears as if you can all apply it to all axes and not simply an individual one?

Comment: You can apply it only on one axis. NumPy's functions usually have the argument `axis` which let you do exactly that! You would have to specify `axis=-1` if I'm not mistaken.