# How to take the end and the begin of a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I wanted to have the end and the begin of a numpy array.

Example:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
print(a[-2:2])
```

What I expected: `[4,5,1]`

But actually it gives an empty array `[]`.

Is it somehow doable?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Numpy arrays are not indexable in this manner (the type of array you are looking for would be called a circular array, I believe.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [circular numpy array indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398220/circular-numpy-array-indices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one approach

roll the array by specified count, so the header rolls after the end
then slice the array

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])


np.roll(a, -1)[2:]
```

OR

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
values_from_start=1
no_of_values = 3

start = len(a) - no_of_values

np.roll(a, values_from_start*(-1) )[start:]
```

```
array([4, 5, 1])
```